# Elasticsearch search not working result

Tags: php, laravel, curl, elasticsearch

I add data add Elasticsearch this code:

```
$data = array("name"=>HelperMC::strToUtf8(trim($name)),
        "urlname"=>HelperURL::strToURL(trim($name)),
        "price"=>number_format(HelperParser::clearTextFromPrice($price), 2, ',', '.'),
        "price_for_filter"=>HelperParser::clearTextFromPrice($price),
        "image"=>$imgname,
        "description"=>HelperMC::strToUtf8($description),
        "keywords"=>HelperMC::strToUtf8($keywords),
        "url"=>$k['url'],
        "sitemap_id"=>intval($sitemapId),
        "shop_id"=>$shop['shop_id'],
        "logo"=>$shop['logo'],
        "key"=>$hashKey,
        "type"=>intval(1),
        "shop_rating_count"=>intval($shop['rating_count']),
        "shop_rating_point"=>intval($shop['rating_point']),
        "created_at"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        "updated_at"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

//create elasticsearch index
HelperES::insertEntry(json_encode($data),$hashKey);
```

My insertEntry Function:

```
private static $elasticBase = "http://localhost:9200/shopping/items";

public static function insertEntry($data_string,$id = false){
    if($id)
        $url = self::$elasticBase."/".$id;
    else
        $url = self::$elasticBase;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    @$result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

and my search Function:

```
public static function search($keyword, $defaultOperator = "OR" ,$start = 0, $size = 25, $from = 0, $to = 10000, $shopsArr = array(),$orderBy = "price", $order = "asc"){
    $searchUrl = self::$elasticBase."/_search";

    if(count($shopsArr) > 0){
        $query = '{
                        "from" : '.$start.', "size" : '.$size.',
                        "query" : {
                            "filtered" : {
                             "query": {
                                "query_string": { "query": "'.$keyword.'",
                                "fields": ["name","urlname"],
                                "default_operator": "'.$defaultOperator.'"
                                }
                              },
                                "filter" : {
                                     "bool" : {
                                        "must" : {
                                            "terms" : { "sitemap_id" : '.json_encode($shopsArr).' }
                                        },
                                        "must" : {
                                            "range" : {
                                                        "price_for_filter" : {
                                                            "from" : "'.$from.'",
                                                            "to"  : "'.$to.'"
                                                        }
                                                      }
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "sort" : [
                                 {"'.$orderBy.'" : {"order" : "'.$order.'", "mode" : "avg"}}
                             ]
                }';
    }else{
        $query = '{
                "from" : '.$start.', "size" : '.$size.',
                "query" : {
                    "filtered" : {
                     "query": {
                            "query_string": { 
                                "query": "'.$keyword.'",
                                "fields": ["name","urlname"],
                                "default_operator": "'.$defaultOperator.'"
                            }
                          },
                        "filter" : {
                            "range" : {
                                "price_for_filter" : {
                                    "from" : "'.$from.'",
                                    "to"  : "'.$to.'"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sort" : [
                             {"'.$orderBy.'" : {"order" : "'.$order.'", "mode" : "avg"}}
                         ]
            }';
    }

    echo $query;    

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $searchUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    @$result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

But my search results not working.

Example: http://azdanaz.com:9200/shopping/items/_search?q=name:telefon&pretty

working but,

http://www.azdanaz.com/arama/telefon

not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the mapping for your `shopping` index, it shows that your `price_for_filter` field is actually a string, not a numeric type. Therefore, your range filter is doing a string comparison, not a numeric comparison. This is filtering out all of your results.

To illustrate, your range is filtering from "0" to "100000".  The `price_for_filter` value of your first expected result is "12.97". When doing a string comparison, "12.97" is greater than "0", however, as a string, it is also greater than "100000", so this result gets filtered out ("12" > "10").

You either need to change the `price_for_filter` field to be a numeric field, or you need to add a new field that is a numeric type and change your range filter to use that new field.

Comment: @ArzuDemir That query is not working like you think.  You're getting three results back, but that's because the prices for those results all start with "10.xx".  When using string comparisons, "10.xx" is < "100000", because the period (.) sorts lower than a 0.  However, what about the next item, with a price of "11.63"?  It is not showing up because, using string comparions, "11.63" > "100000".  Take a look at your mapping: [http://azdanaz.com:9200/shopping/items/_mapping](http://azdanaz.com:9200/shopping/items/_mapping). It shows `price_for_filter` is a string, but it needs to be numeric.

Comment: @ArzuDemir As another demonstration, change "100000" to "9", and you'll see a lot more of your items.

Comment: price_for_filter must only numeric? expample-> incorrect: 2000,49 but correct 200049 ?

Comment: @ArzuDemir No, the `price_for_filter` field itself must be defined as a "float" or a "double", not "string".

Comment: very thanks for help us. You have any example or code for add index elasticsearch  float or a double.